# Please, are there solutions for the problem of hyphenating words

Tags: hyphenation

[image]

Please, there are solutions to the problem of crossword words

Comment: If you want to disable hyphenation then you need `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}`. Is that it?

Comment: perhaps this is a mistranslation but "crossword" doesn't seem to give any hint of the question. Hyphenating words isn't normally considered a problem that needs a solution, adding the hyphens is a major feature of a typesetting system.